# Tips for improving Visio Services performance

Tags: 2010, performance, visio-services

I have a solution with approximately 1MB Visio Drawings which are data bound. I need the drawings to refresh as frequently as possible (which I believe is 1 minute interval).

I'm looking for performance tips to minimise the time for a request to Visio Services. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this whitepaper closely.  It has all the details you need for performance management concerning Visio Services. Microsoft has placed a great deal of effort for performance related instructions for SharePoint 2010 service applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193020.aspx